# using logstash to parse csv file

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash

I have an elasticsearch index which I am using to index a set of documents.

These documents are originally in csv format and I am looking parse these using logstash as this has powerful regular expression tools such as grok.

My problem is that I have something along the following lines

```
field1,field2,field3,number@number#number@number#number@number
```

In the last column I have key value pairs key@value separated by # and there can be any number of these

Is there a way for me to use logstash to parse this and get it to store the last column as the following json in elasticsearch (or some other searchable format) so I am able to search it

```
[
  {"key" : number, "value" : number},
  {"key" : number, "value" : number},
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, You can use [CSV](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/filters/csv) filter to parse out the last column. 
Then, you can use [Ruby](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/filters/ruby) filter to write your own code to do what you need.

```
input {
    stdin {
    }
}

filter {
    ruby {
        code => '
            b = event["message"].split("#");
            ary = Array.new;
            for c in b;
                keyvar = c.split("@")[0];
                valuevar = c.split("@")[1];
                d = "{key : " << keyvar << ", value : " << valuevar << "}";
                ary.push(d);
            end;
            event["lastColum"] = ary;
        '
    }
}


output {
    stdout {debug => true}
}
```

With this filter, When I input

> 1@10#2@20

The output is

```
    "message" => "1@10#2@20",
  "@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2014-03-25T01:53:56.338Z",
 "lastColum" => [
    [0] "{key : 1, value : 10}",
    [1] "{key : 2, value : 20}"
]
```

FYI. Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea the ruby filter existed, I was just about to write my own filter in Ruby and use that instead but this should do the trick very nicely.